# 2^n to n priority encoder w/ continuous assignments

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

n is being parameterized. I have written this code and it does not work when I run with my test bench which I also wrote. everything can be viewed if you scroll down...

```
module p2_encoder
#(
    parameter SIZE_OUT = 3,
    parameter SIZE_IN  = 2 ** SIZE_OUT-1
)
(
    input logic [SIZE_IN :0]    encoder_in,
    output logic [SIZE_OUT:0]    encoder_out,
    output logic [7:0]    test_out
);

assign test_out = SIZE_OUT;
  
genvar i;
  
generate
  for(i = SIZE_IN; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
    assign encoder_out[i] = (encoder_in[i]) ? i : 0;
  end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

test bench is as follows with n=4 for this example, but it should work without n being whatever the user chooses:

```
module test;
parameter ENCODER_OUT  = 4;
parameter ENCODER_SIZE = (2 ** ENCODER_OUT) - 1;


logic clk = 0;
parameter   CLK_PERIOD = 10;    // clock period is 10 time units

////////////////////////

logic [ENCODER_SIZE:0] encoder_in, i, test_out;
logic [ENCODER_OUT:0] encoder_out;

// instantiation
p2_encoder encoder_1(.*);
// defining the parameter of this encoder
defparam encoder_1.SIZE_OUT = ENCODER_SIZE;

// test vectors
initial 

begin 

    $display("\n--------------------");
    // do an exhuastive test using ALL inputs
    // this for loop covers everything until
    // the last, highest input.
    // done this way to prevent infinite 
    // looping
    for(i=0; i <= 2*ENCODER_OUT; i = i + 1)
    begin
        encoder_in = i;
        #1
        $display("input =  %b, output = %d", encoder_in, encoder_out);
    end
    // the last, highest input value
    encoder_in = i;
        #1
    $display("input =  %b, output = %d", encoder_in, encoder_out);
   

    $display("\n --------------------\n");
        
 
    $stop;
end

endmodule
```

testbench results give an incorrect result, which can be seen below. How can I correct my code to get correct results?

```
# input = 0000000000000000, output = 0 
# input = 0000000000000001, output = 0 
# input = 0000000000000010, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000000011, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000000100, output = 0 
# input = 0000000000000101, output = 0 
# input = 0000000000000110, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000000111, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000001000, output = 8 
# input = 0000000000001001, output = 8
```

correct results should look like...

```
# input = 0000000000000000, output = 0 
# input = 0000000000000001, output = 0 
# input = 0000000000000010, output = 1 
# input = 0000000000000011, output = 1 
# input = 0000000000000100, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000000101, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000000110, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000000111, output = 2 
# input = 0000000000001000, output = 3 
# input = 0000000000001001, output = 3
```

I know the error is in the line `assign encoder_out[i] = (encoder_in[i]) ? i : 0` but I don't know what to do to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it in an algorithmic way using generate blocks. Generate blocks are evaluated at a pre-processing step before real program compilation and therefore cannot be conditioned based on dynamical variables.

You can write an expression like the following:

```
assign encoder_out = (encoder_in >> 1) == 1 ? 1 : (encoder_in >> 2) == 1 ? 2 (encoder_in >> 3) == 1 ? 3 : 0;
```

If you can see it is recursive and you need to flatten out the recursion levels manually and cannot use a recursion of loops to do it in generate blocks. You would need a dynamic function with a dynamic loop.

Here is a suggestion. You can call a function from the assign statement. Not sure if this is synthesizable, but it explains a possible alternative to the always blocks.

```
  function logic [SIZE_OUT:0] encode(input  logic [SIZE_IN :0] encoder_in);
    for (int i = SIZE_IN-1; i >= 0; i--) begin
      if (encoder_in[i]) begin
        return i;
      end
    end
      return 0;
  endfunction
        
  assign encoder_out = encode(encoder_in);
```

Comment: I'm still very new to SV and didn't realize functions were an option. That snippet of code did the trick! Thank you very much for your help.